# For which graph classes the fractional chromatic index rounded up equals the chromatic index?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colouring

Let $\chi'_f(G)$ be the fractional chromatic index.

For which graph classes $\lceil \chi'_f(G) \rceil = \chi'(G)$?

Since $\chi'_f(G)$ is computable in polynomial time,
 solving this gives tractable graph classes.

Experiments with Sage suggest this is true for
perfect graphs on up to $8$ vertices, though
Sage's implementation is not inefficient.

Comment: Sage is a free software. If you find a part of it too slow, come and write some code ! :-P

Comment: MO question about perfect graphs: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172032/conjecture-for-perfect-graphs-the-fractional-chromatic-index-rounded-up-equals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known that for any multigraph $G$ on at most 8 vertices, $\chi'(G)$ is the maximum of the maximum degree and the ceiling of the odd-sets bound, see [http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X(96)00364-0](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X%2896%2900364-0) (so what you find with sage is not very surprising).

This recent arXiv manuscript gives some more references for your problem (top of page 3)
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.0757v1.pdf

Beside bipartite graphs, non-trivial classes with the property you're looking for include series-parallel graphs.

Comment: Thank you. Is it known for perfect graphs?

Comment: I tried larger graphs (24 vertices) in sage and it appears true too.